# I copied the code from a YouTube channel, for me is not working but in the video is working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am following a video on how to create a to do list. I followed every line of code that was showed in the tutorial but for me is not working. It should create a list item when i press the button. instead it's giving me the error : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".
Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

```js
// selectors
const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoButton = document.querySelector('.todo-button');
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-List');

// event listeners

todoButton.addEventListener('click', addTodo)


// functions

function addTodo(event) {
  // prevent form from submitting
  event.preventDefault();
  // TODO DIV
  const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
  todoDiv.classList.add('todo');
  // Create LI
  const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.innerText = 'hey';
  newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
  todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
  // check mark button
  const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
  completedButton.innerText = "<i class="fas fa-check "> </i>";
  completedButton.classList.add('complete-btn');
  todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
  // check trash button
  const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
  trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa - trash"> </i>';
  trashButton.classList.add('complete-btn');
  todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
  // append to list
  todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #a8903f, #b94a2b);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

header {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

header,
form {
  min-height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

form input,
form button {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: none;
  background: white;
}

form button {
  color: #d88771;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

form button:hover {
  background: #d88771;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <title>Todo list</title>
</head>

<body>


  <header>
    <h1>Teo's TODO list</h1>
  </header>
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" class="todo-input">
    <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
      <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
    </button>
  </form>
  <div class="todo-containre">
    <ul class="todo-list">

    </ul>
  </div>


  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: line 3, todo-List shouldnt have a capital letter

Comment: Vote to close - Not reproducible or was caused by a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your CSS selectors is wrong. Look at yout HTML file - you have:

```
<ul class="todo-list">
  
</ul>
```

but in your JS you have:

```
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-List');
```

It should be `todo-list`, same as in the HTML:

```
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
```

Also look at this line:

```
completedButton.innerText = "<i class="fas fa-check"> </i>";
```

You escaped string trying to add `class` attribute. It should be:

```
completedButton.innerText = '<i class="fas fa-check"> </i>';
```

You did it correctly a few lines below. Your code editor should highlight this.

Answer (score -1):

line : 26 : put single comma instead of double comma. Either use: single comma within outer double comma or double comma within single comma.

`"<i class='fas fa-check'> </i>"` is correct.

not this one: `"<i class='fas fa-check'> </i>"`

```
 completedButton.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-check'> </i>";
```